# What's the maximum pressure inside a bombardier beetle?

Tags: entomology, biochemistry

[This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11277/how-could-i-scientifically-explain-ice-breath) got me wondering about the pressure inside a [bombardier beetle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_beetle).

Lots of articles mention [pressure](http://creation.com/preliminary-observations-of-the-pygidial-gland-of-the-bombardier-beetle-brachinus-sp), but don't specify the amount of it:

> One study records the velocity of the spray to be within a range of 325 to a stunning 1950 cm/s.
>   [...]
>   Once the muscles around the reservoir squeeze the first amount of
>   reactants through the valve into the reaction chamber, the resulting
>   explosion causes the pressure to rise rapidly in the reaction chamber,
>   forcing shut the one-way valve. The products of the reaction then exit
>   the chamber with a pop and a puff, and the pressure inside the
>   reaction chamber lowers again, falling below the pressure of the
>   collection reservoir, which is still being squeezed by the reservoir
>   muscles.

Calculating from the [spray characteristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spray_characteristics) is beyond me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this study](http://europepmc.org/articles/PMC3565695), model data shows a maximum pressure of **110 kPa**, that's 16 psi and only 1.086 atm:

[image: Model data shows a maximum pressure of 110 kPa]

> The three-phase process involved in the beetles explosive secretory
>   discharge (ESD) process. The inlet size is shown as a proportion of
>   the inlet radius. During the first phase of refill and heating (blue),
>   only the inlet valve is open. During the second phase (red), the
>   chamber is closed. Finally, the third phase (marked by an arrow) is
>   the exhaust phase, when only the outlet valve is open. This phase is
>   significantly shorter than the first two phases. This cycle then
>   repeats with phase 1 starting at approximately 5.1 and again at 7.8
>   ms.